# Too few arguments to function, 0 passed and exactly 1 expected in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing

I have a project in Laravel-5.8.

```
'actionURL' => route('appraisal.appraisal_goals.goal_adjustment_self_review', ['id'=>$employeeId]),
```

From the Notification actionUrl, I passed `['id'=>$employeeId]` into:

```
public function goal_adjustment_self_review($id)
{      
    $goals = AppraisalGoal::where('employee_id', $id)->whereNull('deleted_at')->get();              
    return view('appraisal.appraisal_goals.goal_adjustment_self_review')->with(['goals' => $goals]);
}
```

Then I have this edit controller functions generated from goal_adjustment_self_review($id)

```
public function goal_adjustment_edit($id)
{
    $userCompany = Auth::user()->company_id;
    $userId = Auth::user()->employee_id;  
    $goal           =       AppraisalGoal::findOrFail($id); 

    return view('appraisal.appraisal_goals.goal_adjustment_edit')
            ->with('goal', $goal);
}

public function goal_adjustment_update(UpdateAppraisalGoalAdjustmentRequest $request, $id)
{        
    DB::beginTransaction(); 
     try {
     
    $goal = AppraisalGoal::findOrFail($id);
        $goal->goal_type_id             = $request->goal_type_id;
        $goal->weighted_score           = $request->weighted_score;        
            $goal->save();                          
       
        DB::commit(); 
        
            Session::flash('success', 'Goal Setting Weight is updated successfully');
            return redirect()->route('appraisal.appraisal_goals.goal_adjustment_self_review');
    } catch (Exception $exception) {
        Log::error($exception);
             DB::rollback();
             
            Session::flash('error', 'Action failed! Please try again');
            return redirect()->route('appraisal.appraisal_goals.goal_adjustment_self_review');
    }
}
```

view: goal_adjustment_edit

```
<form action="{{route('appraisal.appraisal_goals.goal_adjustment_update', ['id'=>$goal->id])}}" method="post" class="form-horizontal" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  {{ csrf_field() }}
  <input name="_method" type="hidden" value="PUT">

  <div class="card-body">
    <div class="form-body">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-6">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label"> Weight(%):<span style="color:red;">*</span></label> <input type="hidden" id="goal_weight_balance" value="0" disabled>
            <input id="total_weighted_score" type="text" name="weighted_score" value="{{old('weighted_score',$goal->weighted_score)}}" placeholder="Enter weighted score here" class="form-control" max="120" onkeyup="checkScore(this.value)">
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- /.card-body -->
  <div class="card-footer">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Update</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

route:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'appraisal', 'as' => 'appraisal.', 'namespace' => 'Appraisal', 'middleware' => ['auth']], function () {
  Route::get('appraisal_goals/goal_adjustment_self_review/{id?}', 'AppraisalGoalsController@goal_adjustment_self_review')->name('appraisal_goals.goal_adjustment_self_review');
  Route::get('appraisal_goals/goal_adjustment_edit/{id?}', 'AppraisalGoalsController@goal_adjustment_edit')->name('appraisal_goals.goal_adjustment_edit');
  Route::put('appraisal_goals/goal_adjustment_update/{id?}', 'AppraisalGoalsController@goal_adjustment_update')->name('appraisal_goals.goal_adjustment_update');
});
```

When I submitted the update form above, I got this error:

> ```
> [2020-12-18 20:10:46] production.ERROR: Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers\Appraisal\AppraisalGoalsController::goal_adjustment_self_review(),
> ```
>
> 0 passed and exactly 1 expected

For this line:

```
public function goal_adjustment_self_review($id)
```

How do I get this resolved?

Comment: You can just try to change the signature definition of the method `goal_adjustment_self_review($id = null)` since you are having the route parameter as optional in your route definition. For any such optional route parameter you can also access the values in controller via the request object or helper function like `request()->route('id')`

Comment: BTW, the fact that your controller is at least 1700 lines should be a huge red flag. There is a lot of wasted code here (e.g. running a transaction for a single database query.) Your URIs, method, class, and route names are all very unwieldly as well, leading to needless scanning when trying to understand the code. `UpdateAppraisalGoalAdjustmentRequest`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is very clear, you are not passing a parameter to the method. The method is called by the routing engine, which means you are not passing a route parameter that you should.

Your controller method `goal_appraisal_update()` includes this line (twice for some reason):

```php
return redirect()->route('appraisal.appraisal_goals.goal_adjustment_self_review');
```

Where is the parameter?

---

What you should be doing is using [route model binding](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#route-model-binding) so your controller method looks like this:

```php
public function goal_adjustment_self_review($employee)
{      
    $goals = $employee->appraisal_goals;             
    return view('appraisal.appraisal_goals.goal_adjustment_self_review')
        ->with('goals', $goals);
} 

public function goal_adjustment_edit(AppraisalGoal $goal)
{
    return view('appraisal.appraisal_goals.goal_adjustment_edit')
        ->with('goal', $goal);
}

public function goal_adjustment_update(UpdateAppraisalGoalAdjustmentRequest $request, AppraisalGoal $goal)
{
    try {
        $goal->update($request->only('goal_type_id', 'weighted_score'));
        Session::flash('success', 'Goal Setting Weight is updated successfully');
    } catch (\Exception $exception) {
        Log::error($exception);
        Session::flash('error', 'Action failed! Please try again');
    }
    return redirect()
        ->route('appraisal.appraisal_goals.goal_adjustment_self_review', $goal);
}
```

And then routes can be defined like so:

```php
Route::group(['prefix' => 'appraisal', 'as' => 'appraisal.', 'namespace' => 'Appraisal', 'middleware' => ['auth']], function () {

    Route::get('appraisal_goals/goal_adjustment_self_review/{employee}', 'AppraisalGoalsController@goal_adjustment_self_review')
        ->name('appraisal_goals.goal_adjustment_self_review');

    Route::get('appraisal_goals/goal_adjustment_edit/{goal}', 'AppraisalGoalsController@goal_adjustment_edit')
        ->name('appraisal_goals.goal_adjustment_edit');

    Route::put('appraisal_goals/goal_adjustment_update/{goal}', 'AppraisalGoalsController@goal_adjustment_update')
        ->name('appraisal_goals.goal_adjustment_update');
});
```

Note the route parameters match the name of the method parameters. When type is declared in the method signature, magic happens.